# Example for $\frac1{a_n}\to 0$ and $a_n$ not $\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Currently reading "How to think about analysis". It has a section where it says

> do you see why theorem is true but converse is not? $$\text{Theorem: If  }(a_n)\to\infty\text{ then }\left(\frac1{a_n}\right)\to 0$$

I was able to find couterexamples for converse of other theorems but couldn't find one for this. Any example for its converse?

Comment: What about $a_n  = (-1)^n n$ ?

Comment: @MartinR Thank you. So basically all function whivh approach 0 from negative side also dont fullfill the conver.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a sequence $(a_n)$ of nonzero real numbers we have
$$
 \frac{1}{a_n} \to 0 \iff \left| \frac{1}{a_n}\right | \to 0 \iff
|a_n| \to \infty.
$$
The latter implies $a_n \to \infty$ only if (all but finitely many of)
the $a_n$ are positive.

Generally, we can have that $a_n \to -\infty$ (e.g. $a_n = -n$) or that $a_n$ has no limit at all (e.g. $a_n = (-1)^n n$).